# Item Lable in JSF2 selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf-2, selectonemenu

I am using a selectOneMenu in a JSF 2 applicaiton to allow users to select a day in a month. For some reason I can't get the label, "Select Day" to show up. This is what I am doing:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="startDay" value="#{bean.day}">       
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Day" itemValue=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.days}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The code in the bean is like this:

```
private int day;
private List<Integer>days;
```

Which I'm instantiating in a @PostConstruct init method:

```
days = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for(int i=1; i<=31; i++) {
    days.add(i);            
}
```

Everything works fine, but the value displayed in "1" and not "Select Day." I tried different variations on the tags above but nothing works. What am I missing?

EDIT: I also have a similar widget displaying years, which is initialized in the same way but with the loop starting at 2012. Like this:

```
years = new LinkedList<Integer>();
for(int i=2012; i<=2020; i++) {
    years.add(i);           
}
```

This works fine, showing "Select Year" as expected. So is the issue with the instantiating loop starting at 1? And if so, what's the workaround?

Comment: seems like a bug in primefaces version that you use , try using a stable one, or a newer version... cause it should work http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf

Comment: which version of JSF and server you are using? I tried with JSF 2.1(2.1.1.FCS) and Tomcat 7, it displays first value as 'Select Day'.@Daniel how did you conclude it is primefaces?

Comment: user458248 I'm using myfaces 2.1.4 with tomcat 7. Daniel, it's not primefaces on this page. I'm updating the question to add some info.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in MyFaces 2.1.4 nor Mojarra 2.1.4. Are you sure that `day` isn't just been preinitialized to `1` somewhere?

Comment: Not sure at all... In fact that was the problem. Thank you once again, BalusC! (I had it this way because I'm using the page both for editing, and entering a new auction and I wanted to make sure that when coming back to the page to enter a new auction, once another auction was edited, we remove the edited auction's values. But that's besides the point, I'll figure out what to do with it.)

Comment: Okay, I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine so far. The "problem" as you described will occur if you have preinitialized the `<h:selectOneMenu value>` with exactly the item value. In your case, most likely you've set the value of `day` to `1` somewhere in your *real* code. For example,

```
private int day = 1; // Instead of default 0.
```

or

```
public Bean() {
    setDay(1);
}
```

Etcetera.

---

**Update**: as per your comment:

> I had it this way because I'm using the page both for editing, and entering a new auction and I wanted to make sure that when coming back to the page to enter a new auction, once another auction was edited, we remove the edited auction's values. But that's besides the point, I'll figure out what to do with it.

Put the bean in the view scope instead of the session scope. The session scope is the wrong scope for input forms. It should be used for session specifid data only, such as the logged-in user, its preferences and so on. See also [Communication in JSF2 - Managed bean scopes](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes).

Comment: Yeah, I did set it to 1. Setting it to 0 does what I need. About the ViewScoped, how would I deal with validation? For example if a user tries to start an auction in the past I have to report it back. Doing view scope reinitializes the fields, forcing the user to fill in the form from scratch, which is not what I want. Is there a solution? (I'd love to use view scope and reduce memory in the session.)

Comment: The view scoped bean should not be reinitialized on every postback as long as you return `null` or `void` in action methods. However due to [bug 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492) the view scoped bean will do so if you bind one of its properties to a tag handler attribute. Check [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers) and fix the code accordingly by removing/replacing the tag handlers.

Comment: Thank you very much, BalusC. I changed the returns to null and it works beautifully now as ViewScoped. Am I assuming correctly that this is making the memory demand of the application smaller? Oh, you'll make a JSF developer out of me yet :)